# ASP.NET: how to redirect user to the root folder with location.href?

Tags: javascript, webforms

Let's say user is located in `ADMIN/SomePage.aspx`, and I want the user to be redirected to `SomeOtherPage.aspx` located in the root folder.

`window.location.href = 'SomeOtherPage.aspx'` doesn't work because it's looking for `SomeOtherPage.aspx` in the same folder, i.e. `ADMIN`.

`window.location.href = '/SomeOtherPage.aspx'` works on my local, once I deploy to the test server, it's still not working.

How to redirect from anywhere to the roor folder?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `window.location.href = '/SomeOtherPage.aspx'` should work. check it again.  And make sure if there is no "base" tag on your page head

Comment: I don't see any `base` tag on the page head. It seems like I started to understand why it's now working. In the test server there are several folder for each appliaction. For it work to work, it's should be `https://myServer.com/myAppFolder/SomeOtherPage.aspx`. The reason it's not working, it's because I'm getting  `https://myServer.com/SomeOtherPage.aspx`, skipping `myFolder` in the url.

Comment: Then add a base tag `<base href="https://myServer.com/myAppFolder/" />` into head :)

Comment: Now the application breaks because all the links are point to the test server, even in my local. But, thanks you because I understand the concept of base tag. I've taken the easiest and laziest path. Since I've only that javascript code in the MasterPage, I'm checking whether the request-url has the `localhost` substring on it. Thanks again.